# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI, No type was found that matches the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-routing, system.web.http

When i am hitting the url:
http://localhost/api/adxxx/getDeals/?input=2

I get the following error:

> "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost/api/adxxx/getDeals/?input=2'.",
>
> "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller
>   named 'adxxx'."

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {        
            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(UnityBootstrapper.Initialise());
            config.EnableCors();

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "xxx.services",
                routeTemplate: "webapi/{controller}/{action}"
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "xxx.services_new",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

           FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(config);
        }
    }


[Route("api/adxxx/getDeals/")]
public IHttpActionResult GetDeals(int input)
{
 //code here
}
```

How do i resolve this? Very similar apis having different route are working fine.

This happened when i have added fluent validation to my api. That updated my  System.Web.Http.dll to v5.2.3.0

Comment: do you have RoutePrefix attribute on your controller? if no? then you can move "api/adxxx" to controllers RoutePrefix and leave "getDeals" at method attribute

ending slash looks suspicious also

Comment: Do you have an advantageController?

Comment: sorry, wanted to mask the original names. forgot to change it in error message. edit done now.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your route config for allow parameter

```
[Route("api/adxxx/getDeals/{input}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetDeals(int input)
{
 //code here
}
```

and then you can request it by

```
http://localhost/api/adxxx/getDeals/2
```

Comment: in your controller I ma getting one parameter input but your error showing multiple parameter in url `'http://localhost/api/advantage/getDeals/?cityId=2&sc=0&so=1&pn=1'`, what is actual code one paramter or multiple  ?

Comment: Its actually multiple. but to simplify i had posted one parameter. Changed both now.

Comment: This is action method now: [Route("api/adxxx/getDeals/{input}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetDeals(int input) and this is what i hit from postman: http://localhost/api/adxxx/getDeals/2. But i get IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found error.

Comment: do you have any port number in localhost like `http://localhost:8080` ?

Comment: Port should not be an issue. Since other apis in same project  (other controller) are working fine.